# How do I get the ASP.NET DataPager control to work in an UpdatePanel?

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have a search page with parameters at the top and a search button with results at the bottom.  The entire thing is wrapped in an update panel inside the master page.  After clicking the search button it shows the first page.  However if you click the next button on the DataPager it does not show the second page.  It shows no results for the second page.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Nick has the right idea.  It sounds like you are performing your search and populating your ListView in your OnClick method for your search button.  You need to perform your search (or preferably cache the data the first time around) and bind that to the ListView for each new page that is requested using the DataPager.

You can do this fairly easily by creating a method for the ListView's OnPagePropertiesChanged event.  Perform the search (or pull from the cache) and bind the ListView in that OnPagePropertiesChanged event and your data should populate.  Your C# code might look like this:

```
protected void SearchButton_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PerformSearch();
}

protected void PerformSearch()
{
    // ...Get your data.... //

    ListView1.DataSource = data;
    ListView1.DataBind();
}

protected void ListView1_OnPagePropertiesChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PerformSearch();
}
```

Comment: had the exact same problem as the OP, added the PagePropertiesChanged event handler and that fixed it.

Comment: @Derek could you offer a bit more back ground? Is your datapager inside of the update panel or outside? Its seems bit unclear, are you databinding inside of the OnPagePropertiesChanged event?

Comment: @htm11h - the datapager was not inside an update panel.  the OnPagePropertiesChanged event contains the following lines:

this.pgr.SetPageProperties(e.StartRowIndex, e.MaximumRows, false);
this.BindSource();

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your control isn't binding in the postback, which event are you doing the DataBind() in, and is it under an

`if(!IsPostBack) { }`

wrapper of some sort?

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that your page change event is registered with the Script Manager as it is out of the update panel control. 
ScriptManager.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(DatePager Control);

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of your update pannel do this:

```
       <Triggers>
                                <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="DataPager1" />
                            </Triggers>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem when using a `DataPager` on a data control where `EnableViewState=false`.