# ASP.net Listview and datapager inside ajax update panel

Tags: asp.net, ajax, listview, updatepanel

HI,

is it possible to have a listview with datapager inside an update panel and do asynchronous postback without full page rendering when i do the paging in data pager.

I tried adding both controls inside the update panel, it didnt work
Tried registering with   ScriptManager1.RegisterAsyncPostBackControl(DataPager1) it didnt work too.

any other idea, both my controls are inside update panel. and uses a sqldatasource

Comment: <asp:UpdatePanel ID="updpn" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" >  
    <ContentTemplate>        
       <asp:ListView ID="lvw" runat="server" ItemPlaceholderID="ItemContainer3" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
        <LayoutTemplate>
        
      <ul class="CataloguesList">
        <asp:PlaceHolder ID="ItemContainer3"  runat="server" />
      </ul>
      <asp:DataPager ID="pgr"><!--datapager html -->    </asp:DataPager>
   </LayoutTemplate>
   <ItemTemplate>
    <li> <%# Eval("Name") %>
    </li>
   </ItemTemplate>
       
   </asp:ListView>
    </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>

Comment: posted the code, had a tough time reducing it to 600 characters

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a [similiar question t](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/424705/how-do-i-get-the-asp-net-datapager-control-to-work-in-an-updatepanel)o your problem.